# Push to Heroku denied - "failed to push some refs to 'heroku"

Tags: git, heroku, github, push

I should start by saying I'm totally new to Heroku, and it's all looking pretty to foreign to me right now.

Anyway, I've done the Heroku getting started tutorial, uploading a clone git repo, and this works fine.

I'm now trying to accomplish this with some of my own code, but struggling.

1. First, I go to my app directory in bash.
2. Then I run `heroku create`. This is successful.
3. I then run `git push heroku master` as instructed in the tutorial, and I receive the following errors:

`error: src refspec master does not match any.`

`error: failed to push some refs to 'heroku'`

Would appreciate if someone can explain what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27):

It seems that you have not initiated your master branch properly. Have you commited your files? Try (assuming you are on master branch):

```
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push heroku master:master
```

Another, more direct approach, is to push the HEAD:

```
git push heroku HEAD:master
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're getting this: `error: src refspec master does not match any` when attempting to push to heroku master, then you **might have to change**

`git push heroku master`  to  `git push heroku main`.

(*Assuming this project already existed and you had previously pushed it to heroku master*).

This is due to a recent update made to git where the term master was changed to main. I had the same issue and this worked for my case.

Comment: This worked for me, when pushing an existing repo to heroku for the first time.

Comment: "git push heroku main" is the new command.

Answer (score -7):

I was working on this for the past 3 hours and now i get it clearly.
all you need to do is init with whatever project and all i did it "npm init"