# Heroku "failed to push some refs" when trying to push React app

Tags: javascript, git, heroku, create-react-app

Going by this: https://dev.to/smithmanny/deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-2b6f, I am trying to deploy a simple react app out of the box from create-react-app to Heroku.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install
```

Then add these to package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "npm": "6.12.0",
    "node": "10.16.3"
},
```

Then:

```
heroku login blah...
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
heroku create
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/damp-spire-48480.git (auto-generated name of app)
git push heroku master
```

Then I get this:

```
Enumerating objects: 27666, done.
Counting objects: 100% (27666/27666), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (20069/20069), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27666/27666), 24.31 MiB | 362.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 27666 (delta 5987), reused 27666 (delta 5987)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:  !     Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock
remote: 
remote:        Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
remote:        but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
remote:        dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
remote:        packages or subtle bugs in production.
remote: 
remote:        - To use npm to install your application's dependencies please delete
remote:          the yarn.lock file.
remote: 
remote:          $ git rm yarn.lock
remote: 
remote:        - To use yarn to install your application's dependences please delete
remote:          the package-lock.json file.
remote: 
remote:          $ git rm package-lock.json
remote:     
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/0KU2EM53
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to damp-spire-48480.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/damp-spire-48480.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/damp-spire-48480.git'
```

I've looked at a few SO pages now, and so far not seeing a solution. I should not that I've had a few apps and remotes up there, but I think I've removed all app and remotes, and tried to start from scratch... Unless there's something else to clean up...

I tried this one: [Push to Heroku denied - "failed to push some refs to 'heroku"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331282/push-to-heroku-denied-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-heroku). So I tried: `git push heroku master:master` and `git push heroku HEAD:master` and got the same result each time.

Comment: Make sure that you're using only yarn or npm. If you don't want to use yarn remove yarn.lock file. The same thinking for npm.

Comment: I've pretty much figured out that I had to start fresh without yarn.lock. If there was one in there, and you remove it later, then it still fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If there was one in there, and you remove it later, then it still fails.

It should not, if you remove it *and* commit, recording the deletion:

As explained in Heroku page "[Why is my Node.js build failing because of conflicting lock files?](https://help.heroku.com/0KU2EM53/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-conflicting-lock-files)"

```
git rm yarn.lock
git commit -m "Remove yarn lock file"
git push heroku master
```

And/or

```
git rm package-lock.json
git commit -m "Remove npm lock file"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: I agree that it makes absolutely no sense that it would persist. I don't think I could reproduce my steps to try to see that again. Anyhow, I did start from scratch with a fresh create-react-app app. I can see a fair number of differences that may have caused my issue, and there are certainly more. Anyhow, I did get my app working from going through the steps of that tutorial before adding in later the bulk of my site.